# Variables always the same after first execution?

Tags: c++

I'm porting a python script to C++, which calls a function over thousand times. I've never programmed in C++ so i'm not sure what's happening and couldn't figure out a better title to the question.

This is not my actual function, but it reproduces the same error

```
int maior_sequencia()
{
    int random;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int maior_sequencia = rand() % 6+1;
    printf("%i", maior_sequencia);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i<=100; i++)
    {
        maior_sequencia();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If the first result from maior_sequencia() is 3, then it will output 3333333...
If i run the program again, and the first result is for is 5, it will output 555555...

Why is this happening?

Comment: Call `srand()` only once, at the start of `main`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int maior_sequencia()
{
    int random;
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    //^^This will reset random seed every time you call this function
    int maior_sequencia = rand() % 6+1;
    printf("%i", maior_sequencia);
    return 1;
}
```

Since you reset the random seed every time you call the `maior_sequencia`function, therefore, it will give you same value.

Try to put

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

inside `main` before the for loop instead.

Comment: Alright, that was it, thank you so much. Just another question. srand is based on time(), shouldn't time() be different each time it's called?

Comment: This answer is correct, however, re-seeding your random number on something more "random" is good practice, and nets a better truly "random" number otherwise you see the same sequence of random numbers in a lot of cirucmstances.  See my answer for something I think that is a little more complete.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is two fold.  First your use of srand and your use of time.  When you seed a random number generator using time(), time is the number of seconds from some date in 1973, I forget the exact date, but it's known as linux time.  Since you seed every time, you're resetting the random number generator, this is a good practice, however, since you're seeding it with something returning a number in seconds, it is likely your program is taking less than a second to run.  Either do as someone else suggest, and seed the random number generator only once, or seed in something with a finer granularity... ms is probably acceptable.

Comment: Reseeding PRNG multiple times might actually make it useless. The algorithms behind `rand()` are designed to work when they are seeded once (be it linear congruential generator or something more sophisticated). Reseeding may change the properties of the generator (most importantly its distribution).

Comment: Precisely, when seeking a truly random number, changing its distribution can be a good thing.  Some of the best random number generators in the world use a psuedo random distribution with a random seed or pull from this table in at random intervals determined by environmental factors, such as atmospheric noise or radioactive decay.  Otherwise you see recurring patterns of random numbers... which is inherently not random.  http://www.random.org/  Though you are correct in saying, the practice of this is implementation dependent.

Comment: Usually `rand()` is expected to return values with uniform distribution and that's its main use. The period of a good PRNG can be long enough to be perfectly usable. While most (but not all) PRNGs are not cryptographically neither is a true RNG with non-uniform distribution.

Comment: Yes, but if you want numbers that appear random to the user, without too much work.  For example, for a simple dice game.  You can trick traditional rand() into behaving as such, by re-seeding with a seed that appears to the user as random.  For example, present time in ms, which the user cannot control and has a wide degree of variance, but is very easy to implement.  For mathematical purposes within an application, a pre determined random distribution is fine.  But a truly random number is more practical, and this is the easiest way to do it.